# Automated way of connecting line features with dangles in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, line, network-analyst, dangle

I have a line layer with around 9000 features. There is disconnectivity throughout the dataset  Is there an automated to connect these?
Attached are examples.

[image: Dangle 1]

[image: Dangle 2]

Comment: [Snap tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/editing/snap.htm)?

Comment: I thought that but am unsure of the specified distance tolerance due to amount of features. I don't want to connect lines that do not connect in the real wolrd.

Comment: May be you could use the NEAR tool to generate some measure distances and use that to set the snap distance?  You have provided no information about the lines and their attribution so without further information no one can make any suggestions. Suggest you edit your question to improve and give people more information to help suggest ideas.